# Decode protobufs over UDP

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, protoc

I have a Protobuf serialized data that is being sent over UDP multicast. I read it using socat from bash as follows

```
socat UDP4-RECVFROM:1277,ip-add-membership=239.195.1.2:192.168.254.5,fork,reuseaddr -
```

I want to chain this with protoc in order to keep decoding data in every packet. How can I do that ?
When I do

```
socat UDP4-RECVFROM:1277,ip-add-membership=239.195.1.2:192.168.254.5,fork,reuseaddr - | protoc --decode=proto.Message ./path/to/proto/message.proto
```

The terminal just hangs. Not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be in socat. remove the `fork` portion and it works great.

So essentially

```
socat UDP4-RECVFROM:1277,ip-add-membership=239.195.1.2:192.168.254.5,reuseaddr - | protoc --decode=proto.Message ./path/to/proto/message.proto
```